# Stop page flicker on refresh with componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have been adding a session to persist login and of course have unique sessions for each user in my app. When I am logged in and refresh the page, there is a flicker of the login modal as the state of logged in is false until the the session check completes. I have been reading up on it and it seems that this is solved by having a loading placeholder and to use async/await or promise in the componentDidMount lifecycle. However it is not working. I've tried a few ways and right now I've tried the following, but I am kind of lost as none of the various methods I've tried have worked.

```js
export default class BasePage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      userEmail: null,
      userPassword: null,
      userName: null,
      registerUserForm: false,
      sessionActive: false,
      sessionID: null,
      fullPageLoad: null
    }

    this.checkSession = this.checkSession.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
      await this.checkSession()
      this.setState({
        fullPageLoad: true
      })
    })()
}


// React page body
render() {
  if (this.state.fullPageLoad === null) {
    return(
      <div>Loading ...</div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      // Render page content
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what about this piece of code doesn't work? your render function does not examine anything related to login state.

Comment: Instead of display a loading place holder, while the check session resolves the login modal displays instead which it should not as the user is already logged in and the session is still valid.

Comment: Just so I understand, you don't want the `loading` to appear because the user is already logged in?

Comment: So I want the loading text to show whenever the session is running. With the various ways I've tried this, either the loading ... Is either the only thing shows or it never shows. When it doesn't show, for a split second on page refresh the login modal will appear when for that split second it should show the loading text instead.